# LibreOffice writer truncate html .doc files at 65533 characters?

Tags: php, libreoffice

I generate a .doc html formated file from a PHP script. Everithing work fine, my file is well generated, but if I try to open it with LibreOffice (v4.2.8.2) the file is silently truncated to the 65533th character when displayed.

Is there a workaround ? Is it a bug ? Have you any informations about that?

Comment: What exactly is `"a .doc html formated file"`? Do you mean you generated a file of html markup, and gave it an extension of `.doc`?

Comment: Yes exactly, as MS Word and LibreOffice know how to open these files, it's the easiest way to generate .doc (and .xml) files from PHP.

Comment: Except you're not actually creating a doc, just because MS Word and LibreOffice can read html markup, doesn't mean you've created a doc file.... and perhaps this problem indicates that it isn't such a perfect solution after all

Comment: Yes the solution isn't perfect, but my file is well generated, I can open it with a web browser (or any basic text editor) and I can see that my file is OK. 
Here I wonder why LibreOffice cut my file at 65533th char, we are in 2015 I suppose that software nowadays can handle files that has a "huge" (please, note the quotes surrounding huge) number of character. Here I see that something is coded on 2 Bytes in this software.

Comment: Have you tried OpenOffice?  Sometimes the OpenOffice fork can handle files that cause the LibreOffice fork to hiccup and vice versa.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. All my text was within the `<body>` tag. I broke parts of my text within `<div>` and it worked (it won't work with html5 tags such as `<article>`).
I think that LibreOffice can't handle more than 65533 characters by tags.

In addition to that I also remarked the "same" problem in LibreOffice Calc, if you open a .xls file html formated, it will not display more than 65533 non empty cells (here I didn't find (/searched) a workaround).

I think it's a BIG bug with this software (I didn't test with other such as Ooo or MS Office). At least a warning message might be displayed.

Comment: Try LibreOffice 4.3 or later. Sounds most likely like the famous paragraph size limitation in writer (a 10 year OOo bug) that was fixed in LibreOffice 4.3 (https://wiki.documentfoundation.org/ReleaseNotes/4.3#Raise_limit_of_characters_in_paragraphs)

Comment: Thanks for your explanations, in fact I used the OOo version from my distrib repo.